# AlarmManager not calling BroadcastReceiver after specific interval of time

Tags: android

I want to call a `BroadcastReceiver` after specific interval of time. `BroadcastReceiver` is calling but it is not calling exactly after 10 seconds sometimes it call is 20 sec sometimes more than 20 seconds. I want to call `BroadcastReceiver` exactly after 10 seconds

This is the code of `MainActivity`

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SampleReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntent,0);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, wakeupTime,1000 * 10, pendingIntent);
```

This is code of broadcastreceiver

```
public class SampleReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.e("Brodcast","receiver");
    }
}
```

This is my log file

```
09-05 14:48:21.444 18222-18222/com.loconav.partners.tracker E/Brodcast: receiver
09-05 14:49:21.509 18222-18222/com.loconav.partners.tracker E/Brodcast: receiver
09-05 14:50:31.578 18222-18222/com.loconav.partners.tracker E/Brodcast: receiver
09-05 14:51:21.618 18222-18222/com.loconav.partners.tracker E/Brodcast: receiver
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39036001/android-how-to-run-background-service-periodically/39036118#39036118 this will help

Comment: I want to repeat after specific seconds. It is calling but not after specific interval of time

Comment: @SumitMarwha That's because repeating alarms are inexact on API level 19+. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) of `AlarmManager`:

> Note: **Beginning with API 19 (KITKAT) alarm delivery is inexact: the OS
>   will shift alarms in order to minimize wakeups and battery use.** There
>   are new APIs to support applications which need strict delivery
>   guarantees; see `setWindow(int, long, long, PendingIntent)` and
>   `setExact(int, long, PendingIntent)`. Applications whose
>   targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will continue to see the
>   previous behavior in which all alarms are delivered exactly when
>   requested.

Exact repeating is not possible currently with a single set of an alarm on API level 19+.

If you would like your repeating alarm to fire exactly when you want it, then you should use `setExact()` (or `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()` according to your needs) and reschedule it every time it fires.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whats in *wakeupTime*.
The code works for me as

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),1000*10,pendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, use [ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP) type, because you don't need fire alarm at a specific time of day. When you use rtc time, it can be updated by the system - when it syncs with time server, and your alarm could be never fire up at all.

Second, do not use BroadcastReceivers defined as subclasses of Activity - they should be set up in AndroidManifest.xml, because if your activity is destroyed - you will never receive your Intent.

Comment: Well, if you need something to be done every 10 seconds, while Activity is running - use TimerTask or Thread or something. 
BroadcastReceiver's should be declared in Manifest and used without running instance of Activity.

Answer (score 0):

I thinking you have to provide unique request code to get broadcast method.

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SampleReceiver.class);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, uniqueRequestCode, myIntent,0);
                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, wakeupTime,1000 * 10, pendingIntent);
```

> uniqueRequestCode could be the System.currentTimeInMilliSecond